# how to type value dropdown list in SSRS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a dropdown list on SSRS report.
But I have many value in filter.
So I want to type value in dropdown list  parameter.
How can I do like this?

Maybe ı can do autocomplete option in parameter. but ı don't know how can ı do:(

please help me about this issue

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not possible, but the workaround you can do is to have another parameter where user can type-in a keyword then you use that parameter to filter the dataset connected to the main parameter.

Comment: you mean you should use dropdown list or  type-in a keyword on parameter:( am I right?

Comment: yeah, the first one will be a type-in parameter then the second one will be a drop down list (multi-select or single). So what will happen is, when a user enter a keyword on the 1st parameter, the 2nd parameter will auto refresh to filter out all values that does not contain the keyword from the 1st parameter.

Answer (score 1):

maybe I can use add new parameter which type is textbox 
so I can show use dropdown and textbox field for one parameter in same report.
but I could not find How can I do like this
I want to have two options.

[image]

1- If users want to use dropdown list for order they should use dropdown list parameter and textbox must be invalid or 
textbox must be set in dropdown value.

2 - Or if users want to type with keyboard manuelly for order, dropdown list must be invalid or dropdown must be show just type in textbox value.
I added screenshot.

Do you have some suggestions? How can I do like this?
My customers want to use dropdown list and type in manuelly in textbox for same parameter on one report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Aldrin as suggesting that you use another parameter to filter you currant parameter. Let's say you have your parameter (@CurrentParam) and it contains a long list of Countries. You could add another parameter (call it @SearchParam) which has nothing set in the available list so you can just type anything in. The dataset query to populated available list for @CurrentParam woould read something like

```
SELECT Country FROM Countries WHERE Country like '%' + @SearchParam + '%'
```

If you type, for example,  "uni" into @SearchParam then click on the country parameter drop down, you would get a filtered list containing "United Kingdon", "United States" etc...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try your suggestions:)

Comment: Hello Alan, I can try your suggestion too but I have just working on ssrs that why I don't know very well. I guess you said I should create two parameter(CurrentParam is dropdown , SearchParam is textbox with autocomplete). but I don't understand very well. should I create new dataset for searchparam? could you explain me step by step:)